# Flutter debug run on iOS stuck at "Waiting for observatory port"

Tags: ios, flutter

Seemingly out of nowhere I can't run my Flutter app on my physical iPhone (iOS 14.6) in debug mode anymore. I can get it to run in release mode on my real device and debug mode on a simulator though.

I found similar issues on SO but most of them were Android related and I tried all non-Android-related solutions I could find, like: `flutter clean`, upgrading the flutter version to the latest stable release, `flutter pub cache repair`, deleting the build folder, `pod install,` pod update`, reinstalling the flutter sdk, rebooting my macbook, rebooting my iPhone, you name it. But with no luck.

After deploying on the device, it gets stuck at `Application launched on the device. Waiting for observatory port.` for a minute or so and after a timeout it ends with this error:

```
...

[ +346 ms] [ 52%] CreatingStagingDirectory
[        ] [ 57%] ExtractingPackage
[        ] [ 60%] InspectingPackage
[  +16 ms] [ 60%] TakingInstallLock
[  +37 ms] [ 65%] PreflightingApplication
[ +272 ms] [ 65%] InstallingEmbeddedProfile
[   +5 ms] [ 70%] VerifyingApplication
[ +726 ms] [ 75%] CreatingContainer
[   +5 ms] [ 80%] InstallingApplication
[   +7 ms] [ 85%] PostflightingApplication
[   +1 ms] [ 90%] SandboxingApplication
[   +7 ms] [ 95%] GeneratingApplicationMap
[  +59 ms] [100%] Installed package build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app
[ +100 ms] ------ Debug phase ------
[        ] Starting debug of 00008101-00191DEA2130001E (D53pAP, D53pAP, uknownos, unkarch) a.k.a. 'iPhone 12 Pro' connected through USB...
[ +970 ms] [  0%] Looking up developer disk image
[  +17 ms] [ 95%] Developer disk image mounted successfully
[ +373 ms] [100%] Connecting to remote debug server
[        ] -------------------------
[  +87 ms] (lldb) command source -s 0 '/tmp/6DF9D3E0-6EED-4F1F-B6BA-9BEA141ED784/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-00008101_00191DEA2130001E'
[        ] Executing commands in '/tmp/6DF9D3E0-6EED-4F1F-B6BA-9BEA141ED784/fruitstrap-lldb-prep-cmds-00008101_00191DEA2130001E'.
[        ] (lldb)     platform select remote-ios --sysroot '/Users/paul/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/14.6 (18F72)/Symbols'
[        ]   Platform: remote-ios
[        ]  Connected: no
[        ]   SDK Path: "/Users/paul/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/14.6 (18F72)/Symbols"
[        ] (lldb)     target create "/Users/paul/Projects/SchipholRedesign/vliegmeister/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app"
[+1352 ms] Current executable set to '/Users/paul/Projects/SchipholRedesign/vliegmeister/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app' (arm64).
[        ] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_device_app="/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E80524D-96A9-485A-B4D6-5D111AD4CE6E/Runner.app"
[        ] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_connect_url="connect://127.0.0.1:52803"
[        ] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_output_path=""
[        ] (lldb)     script fruitstrap_error_path=""
[        ] (lldb)     target modules search-paths add /usr "/Users/paul/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/14.6 (18F72)/Symbols/usr" /System
"/Users/paul/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/14.6 (18F72)/Symbols/System"
"/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E80524D-96A9-485A-B4D6-5D111AD4CE6E"
"/Users/paul/Projects/SchipholRedesign/vliegmeister/build/ios/iphoneos" "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3E80524D-96A9-485A-B4D6-5D111AD4CE6E"
"/Users/paul/Projects/SchipholRedesign/vliegmeister/build/ios/iphoneos" /Developer "/Users/paul/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/14.6
(18F72)/Symbols/Developer"
[  +21 ms] (lldb)     command script import "/tmp/6DF9D3E0-6EED-4F1F-B6BA-9BEA141ED784/fruitstrap_00008101_00191DEA2130001E.py"
[   +4 ms] (lldb)     command script add -f fruitstrap_00008101_00191DEA2130001E.connect_command connect
[        ] (lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_00008101_00191DEA2130001E.run_command run
[        ] (lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_00008101_00191DEA2130001E.autoexit_command autoexit
[        ] (lldb)     command script add -s asynchronous -f fruitstrap_00008101_00191DEA2130001E.safequit_command safequit
[        ] (lldb)     connect
[  +32 ms] (lldb)     run
[ +373 ms] success
[        ] Application launched on the device. Waiting for observatory port.
[+30021 ms] Installing and launching... (completed in 49.1s)
[   +1 ms] Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Paul.
[   +6 ms] "flutter run" took 260,021ms.
[   +4 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:644:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[   +2 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 0ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] (lldb) process detach
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

I tried

This is my `$ flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.0.6, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-NL)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at /Users/paul/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (10 weeks ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/paul/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.24.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro (mobile) • 00008101-00191DEA2130001E            • ios            • iOS 14.6
    • iPhone 12 Pro (mobile)      • F10EEAA2-7C15-4D4E-92EC-9F46BF814723 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5
      (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114

• No issues found!
```

Does anyone recognize this issue on iOS and maybe have any idea what it could be?

Comment: After many hours of trying all solutions I could find, I ended up reinstalling XCode and the Flutter SDK. That did the trick but didn't explain what was causing this issue.

Comment: I tried reinstalling them but still no success. Did anyone get an answer?